# Type-safe & generic NSMapTable

Tags: objective-c, swift

Is there a Swift version of `NSMapTable` like for `NSArray` (`Array`), `NSDictionary` (`Dictionary`) and `NSSet` (`Set`)?

AFAIK, none exists. If that's the case, is it possible to write an implementation of `NSMapTable` in pure Swift?

PS: This question is for two reasons. Firstly, I'd like to have a generic version of `NSMapTable`. Secondly, I'm curious to know if Swift has the tools needed for implementing a collection that stores weak values and removes them automatically when the values become nil.

Comment: You can wrap NSTable with your custom class. That way you wouldn't need to invent wheel

Comment: @mustafa That's true, though I don't think you can store `Enum`s or `Structs` that way.